# location of settings.py for django project hosted in Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I've problems running the simplest django project within GAE.

After running `django-admin startproject myproj` (Using django 1.4 from Google SDK), the folder hierarchy look as:

```
+ myproj (root folder of project)
  - manage.py
  + myproj (a sub folder for the project files)
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
```

I then add the usual app.yaml **to the root folder** - that is to the same folder where manage.py is.

```
application: u-pavarotti
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.4"

builtins:
- django_wsgi: on
```

syncdb, dbshell, shell ... works great. Even `manage.py runserver` works file. However, trying to run `dev_appserver` fails. The exception I get is:

`ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings'`.

Well, taking a look at google/appengine/ext/django/main (which `django_wsgi` is basically setting a URL handler for .* to the google.appengine.ext.django.main.app) is appears that it expect to find settings in the python path. But without doing anything, the module to import is `myproj.settings` (as myproj isn't in the path).

Now, adding .../myproj/myproj (the lower folder) to the PYTHONPATH solve everything on my dev machine, but as I have no control on the search path on the GAE deployment - this solution won't work.

I can move all files, or just settings.py up to the upper myproj, or move app.yaml down (kinda same thing), but it requires various changes form the default genereated settings.py - and I don't this is the way to go. Alternatively, I can write my own handler, which will instantiate django.core.handlers.wsge.WSGIHandler (old tutorials used to do that) - again, seems against the intention of at least the creators of the 'builtin' attribute of app.yaml.

I wonder how everyone else is solving this issue, and what is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in your app.yaml:

```
env_variables:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'myproj.settings'
```