# GAE: ImportError while using google-auth

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, importerror, google-authentication

I am using `google-auth` to allow firebase authentication in my GAE project.

Everything works fine when I run the code locally using `dev_appserver.py` or when I deploy it to google app engine.

But I get this `ImportError` exceptions when I try to use Django's `manage.py` script to create/run migrations.

```
ImportError: Could not import 'firebase.authentication.FirebaseAuthentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. ImportError: No module named auth.transport.requests.
```

The `google-auth` module is installed under `lib` directory and has this structure:

`- lib
        - google
            - auth
            - oauth2`

These import cause the `ImportErrors`:

```
import google.auth.transport.requests
from google.oauth2 import id_token
```

My guess is that there might be naming conflicts as other imports work fine.

Please help!

Comment: potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878577/location-of-settings-py-for-django-project-hosted-in-google-app-engine

Comment: My ImportError is related with the fact that python doesn't find the `google-auth` module in `lib` directory. `dev_appserver.py app.yaml` works fine.

Comment: I mean that's because you run `manage.py` as a standalone application, not as a GAE one. The post I suggested seems to include the GAE app settings when running `manage.py`, which could mean it directs it to the libraries that the GAE app is using. If I understand it correctly, I'm not really familiar with django.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 3rd party libraries that are not included in [this list](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27), then you'll have to add them manually since you have done that by adding lib folder and including all the package folder follow these steps.

Create your_app_directory/[appengine_config.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-flask-skeleton/blob/master/appengine_config.py) file.

Add these following lines inside that file

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```

This should solve the import error problem.

Comment: Thanks Bravin for your quick response.

I already do have appengine_config.py, which, I guess, is why `dev_appserver.py` works fine an recognizes the libraries. But `python manage.py makemigrations` results to this ImportError.

It has to do something with the module name `google`, as other imports work fine. Maybe there is a conflict between googlecloudsdk and the google-auth libraries?